# Re-run git add

Tags: git

I am just starting indexing files in a new repository. I ran `git add .` and all files were added. After pushing them I noticed a hook was not working. I'd like to do `git add .` again to push the same files, again. But clearly `git add .` does not add anything new. What is the proper way of resetting the index to nothing so everything gets added again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to re-run git post-commit hook, just add some small commit (update indentation in README or something) and push to the repo again.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply force-push the previous commit (in case it's not a root commit):

```
git push origin +master^:master
```

This moves master in the remote repository one commit back (`+` is used to allow non-fast forward updates). This will run your commit hook with your previous commit; if you don't want that disable your hook during this operation.

Now, simply push the commit again, which should run your commit hook again with the same set of changes when it wasn't working (after `add .`):

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git reset HEAD~` to reset the current head to the previous commit, then re-add the files and commit.

This will cause your branch to diverge from the remote; you'll then want to `git push -f` to overwrite the remote branch with your new one.

Comment: @knittl `HEAD~` and `HEAD~1` are synonyms.

Comment: @meager: they are? news to me. I only know `HEAD^ == HEAD~1` – ok, just tested, it works. Didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: @knittl `HEAD~` == `HEAD~1`; `HEAD~~` == `HEAD~2`; `HEAD~~~` == `HEAD~3` etc.

Comment: @knittl HEAD^ is the first parent. HEAD^2 is second parent and so on. HEAD~n is the nth generation grand parent, following FIRST parents.

Comment: @manojlds: yes, I know that; but I did not know that `HEAD~` defaults to `~1`. @meagar: interesting. I use always `HEAD^^^^…` for such cases (which also lets me specify the parent of merge commits)

Comment: @manojlds `HEAD~n` is the n-th generation *parent*, not *grand* parent. `HEAD~1` is not the *grand* parent, is is the direct parent of `HEAD`.

Comment: @Meagar - says so in the doc: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html. And it comes down to English usage I suppose.

Comment: @manojlds True. I guess more accurately `HEAD~n` would be the nth generation grand parent for n > 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a `git add` the files are added to git tracking. There is no need to re-add these files, when you can simply modify and commit them again (then push). If you wish to re-add you could theoretically `git rm` them put them back in the repo, make changes and then perform the add again. You could also reset the repo to a previous commit, but both of these seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below to replicate what you are doing ( I am saying this because the commit may depend on files being added etc, so a simple change to another file and pushing might not work):

```
git reset HEAD~
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple, easy to follow, solution:

1. Amend your previous commit 
   `git commit --amend`
2. Force push it with
   `git push -f`